# Disable mouse scrolling in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mouseevent

How to disable mouse scrolling in VC++, which is previously activated & handled via OnMouseWheel?

EnableScrollBar(SB_BOTH,ESB_DISABLE_BOTH) can disable the arrows & scrollbar but not mousescroll.

How can mouse scrolling be stopped?

Comment: Add an OnMouseWheel hander that does nothing?

Comment: If an empty OnMouseWheel handler doesn't work, catch the PreTranslate and return TRUE (i.e. processed).

Comment: @Jonathan Potter,@Alexis Wilke thanks, it worked.